# product collection from sub-categories id from object manager where subcategory was created in custom category which located out of root category

Tags: magento-2.0

I want all product of particular category on basis of category ID.

I have already tried below code but not solved:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$cateinstance = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$allcategoryproduct = $cateinstance->create()->load($cateid)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

[{"entity_id":"245","sku":"U001","type_id":"simple","category_id":null,"cat_index_position":"0","product_image":"\/p\/e\/peach-boy-boys-shirts_1_a8c05a1421e5dcf8ad5308398e0b3591_1.jpg","small_image":"\/p\/e\/peach-boy-boys-shirts_1_a8c05a1421e5dcf8ad5308398e0b3591_1.jpg","thumbnail":"\/p\/e\/peach-boy-boys-shirts_1_a8c05a1421e5dcf8ad5308398e0b3591_1.jpg","productName":"DY Andheri Peach School Uniform","price":"500.0000","isProductInStock":19,"isProductEndorsed":false,"option_collection":[]},{"entity_id":"250","sku":"U003","type_id":"configurable","category_id":null,"cat_index_position":"0","product_image":"\/0\/a\/0aea950b-1c0a-4adf-85ce-c521555462651534842479667-chalk-by-pantaloons-girls-dresses-4851534842479574-1.jpg","small_image":"\/0\/a\/0aea950b-1c0a-4adf-85ce-c521555462651534842479667-chalk-by-pantaloons-girls-dresses-4851534842479574-1.jpg","thumbnail":"\/0\/a\/0aea950b-1c0a-4adf-85ce-c521555462651534842479667-chalk-by-pantaloons-girls-dresses-4851534842479574-1.jpg","productName":"DY Andheri Girls School Uniform","price":"450.0000","isProductInStock":0,"isProductEndorsed":false,"option_collection":[{"sku":"DY Andheri Girls School Uniform-S","product_id":"250","attribute_id":"151","default_title":"Size","value_index":"30","display_label":"S","price":"450.0000"},{"sku":"DY Andheri Girls School Uniform-M","product_id":"250","attribute_id":"151","default_title":"Size","value_index":"31","display_label":"M","price":"450.0000"},{"sku":"DY Andheri Girls School Uniform-L","product_id":"250","attribute_id":"151","default_title":"Size","value_index":"32","display_label":"L","price":"450.0000"},{"sku":"DY Andheri Girls School Uniform-XL","product_id":"250","attribute_id":"151","default_title":"Size","value_index":"33","display_label":"XL","price":"450.0000"}]}]
```

Comment: What is the result of the code that you've posted? What happens? What errors if any?

Comment: I Want product collection on basis of category outside of ROOT Category

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific category product collection by

```
        $categoryId = 3;
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

        $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

**You can replace categoryId with your category Id and collection will return all product which is enabled and visibility is set to catalog search and that belong to specify category**

Comment: Its Shows ProductCollection for category Inside Root Category Not for Outside Root category, my category placed outside of root